# Anchor tags removing hash tag in URL

Tags: url

I have a long page with 5 anchor tags. The pull down menu is /boxoffice/season#1,  /boxoffice/season#2,  /boxoffice/season#3, etc.

However when I go to the menu and click on the link it works for about one second and then it pops back up to the top of the page.

I can see the URL change in the address bar from  /boxoffice/season#1 to just boxoffice/season. It auto removes the #1.

Is this an EE thing for some other conflict. Looking for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a JS conflict to me. This shouldn't be anything related to EE.

Comment: +1 Definitely not an EE thing.

Comment: yes, it was a js conflict.